# where I should put aws access key in blazor maui application

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, mudblazor

I am going to integrate AWS SNS service into .NET Blazor MAUI App.
Where I put the AWS Access Key and Secret key in Blazor MAUI App.

In most articles, it says put those keys in Web.config.
But I can't find web.config

Answer (score 0):

What is your platform? If you run in azure then the keyvault is where your secrets should go.
Web config should not contain secrets, as they end up in the code repo etc.
appsettings.json you may have instead of web.config, the same applies.